# Breezejs date always Dec 31, 1969

Tags: date, knockout.js, breeze

I am trying to bind to a date using breeze and knockout. The data returned from the BreezeController is as expected. But I see this in the debugger:

```
  TripDate: function dependentObservable() {
__ko_proto__: function (evaluatorFunctionOrOptions, evaluatorFunctionTarget, options) {
_latestValue: Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
__proto__: Invalid Date
```

The json data coming in back from the database server is: 
`TripDate: "2013-07-21T00:00:00.000"` 
Any idea why the date is "Invalid"?

Answer (score 0):

use this in view model

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
    $(element).datepicker(options);

    //handle the field changing
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
    });

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
        $(element).datepicker("destroy");
    });

},
//update the control when the view model changes
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
}
};
```

then in html

```
data-bind="datepicker:tripDate"
```

Now you will get what u need ....also you can save the updated date

Answer (score 0):

check it if you just want to display

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateString = {
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var value = valueAccessor(),
        allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
    var pattern = allBindings.datePattern || 'MM/dd/yyyy';
    $(element).text(valueUnwrapped.toString(pattern));
}
}
```

in html replace 'datepicker' with 'dateString'

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I was unwrapping the value prior to attempting to format (not shown).  To be more specific the date value in the json data is correct but when I unwrap the observable to format the date the value contained in the observable is incorrect.  Not sure what to do next.